# RStudio shiny runApp fails in working directory

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have a folder of R Projects called "R Projects".  R Projects is my default RStudio working directory.  I created the initial shiny tutorial app App-1 in a project folder called App-1 under R Projects.

When I attempt to run App-1; runApp("App-1") from the App-1 project I get the error message:

```
Error in shinyAppDir(x) : No Shiny application exists at the path "App-1"
```

When I modify runApp: runApp("App-1", appDir = getwd()) it throws the error:

```
Listening on domain socket App-1
Error in startPipeServer(port, mask, handlerManager$createHttpuvApp()) : 
  Failed to create server
```

However when I close the App-1 project and run App-1 from the default directory; Project (None), App-1 runs as intended as a shiny app.

I'm sure this is probably a trivial problem.  Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: did you compare the working directory and the app path and see if they match.

Answer (score 20):

Man, I'm an idiot.  To run a shiny app in the app's directory merely enter:

`runApp()` in the console without any arguments.

Comment: It's okay. Mark it as correct, it may help someone. And you don't have to call yourself an idiot. It invites downvoting.

Comment: I got this error when pressing the 'Run App' button in RStudio submitted this command: shiny::runApp(''). Removing the blank argument as in the answer fixed it